# Difference between direct LEFT JOIN chain and SELECT sub-query LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a MySQL JOIN consisting 4 tables:

Direct chaining

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3... col12 FROM
   (((tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2...) LEFT JOIN tbl3 ...) LEFT JOIN tbl4);
```

Sub-SELECT

```
(SELECT col10 .. col12 FROM 
  (SELECT col7 .. col9 FROM 
     (SELECT col1, ... col6 FROM tbl1
          LEFT JOIN tbl2) AS J1
            LEFT JOIN tbl3) AS J2
               LEFT JOIN tbl4...)
```

**Is there an efficiency difference between the two methods?** My gut feeling is that sub-selects discard unnecessary rows and columns with the SELECT ... WHERE clause and makes JOINs faster and less memory intensive. Any advice? How about other databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on your tables size and filtered data by queries.

Condition1:
If your table size is normal (suppose all tables have approx 5000 rows) and you are fetching data from tables with out any filteration then there should not be any difference in both queries even first query can give better performance.

Condition2:
If your tables have bulky data suppose rows in billions but after filtering data actual data set has suppose near about approx. below 100 rows then 2nd query can be better.

There is no hard and fast rule, you have to check your query performance various manner as per your table data size and your requirement. The thumb rule is if we can reduce data size for joins with different tables then it will increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

it will depend on the size of the table normally your first query will be more faster then the second because the evaluation period be less when compared with second.